# Android : setonclicklistener in adapterview cannot be applied

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am getting error in `l.setOnClickListener(this);` it says something `setOnclicklistner` in `adapterview` cannot be applied etc

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Adapter;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    ListView l;
    String[] days={"Sunday","monday","tuesday","wedensday","thursday","friday","saturday"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,days);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);
        l.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView temp=(TextView)view;
        Toast.makeText(this,""+temp.getText()+" "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: your onItemClick gets called or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` :

```
l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you, Nika. I was having problems with my homework and this was the solution. The textbook made the error of using setOnClick... instead of setOnItemClick...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

OR

```
    l.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: it worked but can u explain why setOnClickListener didntl worked but setOnItemClickListener worked, isn't it same